# Retrofit 2 Unable to Use Delete tag with Body

Tags: android, networking, retrofit2

I have my call Implemented as

```
 @HTTP(method = "DELETE", hasBody = true)
        @DELETE("groups/{groupId}/members/remove")
        Call<GroupRemoveUserModel> putRemoveUser(@Path("groupId") int groupId, @Body GroupRemoveUserModel groupRemoveUserModel);
```

where model code is as follows :

```
public final class GroupRemoveUserModel {

    public GroupRemoveUserModel(int userId){
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

However when I call the method with appropriate parameters it doesn't work moreover cannot get any stack trace as well already using okhttp logger for debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "groups/{groupId}/members/remove", hasBody = true)
Call<GroupRemoveUserModel> putRemoveUser(@Path("groupId") int groupId, @Body GroupRemoveUserModel groupRemoveUserModel);
```

Comment: This workaround is throwing an error for me:
"retrofit.RetrofitError: UserService.delete: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @ GET, @ POST, etc.)."